# Group cell-array row by an ID in another row

Tags: matlab, matrix, grouping, cell-array

I have got this cell-array:

```
QueueArr = ...
{   [1]    [5]    [1]    [2]    [1]    [ 1]    [ 5]    [ 1]    [ 2] ;  
    [6]    [8]    [7]    [9]    [5]    [10]    [18]    [17]    [19] }
```

Now I want to group the second row depending on the first one. My result cell-array should look like this:

```
loopCell = ...
{    [          1]    [          2]    [          5] ;
     [6 7 5 10 17]    [       9 19]    [       8 18] }
```

I solved this problem with this code:

```
%// convert from cell to a matrix
loopMatrix = cell2mat(QueueArr);
%// get the unique elements from the first row
loopMatrixUnique = unique(loopMatrix(1,:));
%// create the result cell
loopCell = cell(2,size(loopMatrixUnique,2));
%// iterate through the unique indexes
for i = 1:size(loopMatrixUnique,2)
    %// saving the first row
    loopCell{1,i} = loopMatrixUnique(i);
    %// calculating the grouped elements
    loopCell{2,i} = loopMatrix(2,loopMatrix(1,:) == loopMatrixUnique(i));
end
```

**My question now is whether there is an easier or more ideal solution to my problem.**

Comment: Have you had a look at `accumarray`? It's basically made for this task. You'll find the third output of `unique` helpful to generate the `subs` input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it myself with [`accumarray`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/accumarray.html#bt4vy9n-5).
thx to @Dan for the hint.

```
%// save the second row
sections = [QueueArr{2,:}];

%// get unique chapters and subs
[chapters, ~, subs] = unique([QueueArr{1,:}]);

%// create the grouped cell-array 
groups = accumarray(subs, sections, [], @(x) {x});

%// create the result cell-array
loopCell = [num2cell(chatpers); groups.'];
```

Comment: Note you don't need `cell2mat` but can use the same technique you used for `sections` in your call to `unique`:  `... = unique([QueueArr{1,:}])`. I'm not sure which is more efficient though

Answer (score 1):

As you were told in comments, the 3rd output of `unique` is very usefull for your case.

Once you have that, `cellfun` can also be used to rebuild your cell array quickly:

```
b = cell2mat(QueueArr(2,:)) ; %// convert bottom line to array for convenience

[C,~,ic]= unique( cell2mat(QueueArr(1,:)) ) ;

R = [ num2cell(C) ; ...                                             %// top row
      cellfun( @(x) b(ic==x) , num2cell(1:length(C)) , 'uni',0)  ]  %// bottom row
```